# Show the graph is Jordan region with volume 0

Tags: analysis

Let $f \colon [a, b] →\mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Then prove that the graph of $f$, 
$$\operatorname{Graph}(f) := \{\,(y, x) \in \mathbb R^2\mid y = f(x), x \in [a, b]\,\}$$ is a Jordan region, and it has Jordan content $0$.

So I need to show that there exist an $\epsilon >0$ such that the volume is $<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f$ is *uniformly* continuous. Thus given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that yadda yadda.
With $n=\lfloor\frac{b-a}{2\delta}\rfloor+1$ we see that
the graph is contained in 
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^n[x_k-\delta,x_k+\delta]\times [f(x_k)-\epsilon,f(x_k)+\epsilon] $$
where $x_k=a+\frac {2k-1}{2n}(b-a)$. This shows that the Jordan content is $$\le n\cdot 2\delta\cdot 2\epsilon\le ((b-a)+2\delta)2\epsilon .$$
As we may assume wlog. that $\delta<1$, this expression becaomes arbitrarily small, showing that the Jordan content is indeed $0$.